# How to install extensions on Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to install an extension for my Magento store. My version of is 
Magento ver. 2.1.15. Now when i install the extension, it is not visible at **Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced**

This is the steps i followed to install the extension

```
 1.Extracted my extension folder into my root            
 2.php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 3.php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 4.php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But i still cannot find the extension in my store. What could be causing this as i am not seeing any error anywhere ?

PS: I just started working on Magento.

**Acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="GlobalSms_Notify::sms" title="GlobalSms" sortOrder="100">
                    <resource id="GlobalSms_Notify::config" title="Config" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="GlobalSms_Notify::sms_config" title="Configuration" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="globalsms_notify" sortOrder="2000">
            <label>GlobalSms</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="globalsms_notify_configuration" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

            <label>Basic Configuration</label>
            <tab>globalsms_notify</tab>
            <resource>GlobalSms_Notify::sms</resource>
            <group id="basic_configuration" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[Basic Configuration&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>Setting API Account</i>]]></label>
                <field id="notify_username" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enter GlobalSms Username</label>
                    <comment>Enter your GlobalSms SMS API Username</comment>
                    <tooltip>Your username must be the same as your GloablSms api username</tooltip>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="notify_password" type="password" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enter GlobalSms Password</label>
                    <comment>Enter your GlobalSms SMS API Password</comment>
                    <tooltip>Your password must be the same as your GlobalSms api password</tooltip>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>


    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only asking because you explicitly said:

> PS: I just started working on Magento.

Did you extract your module to `magentoroot/app/code/Vendor/Module` (where it belongs) or to the magento root?

If it is under `magentoroot/app/code/Vendor/Module` check if your module is registered properly.

```
bin/magento module:status
```

If your module does not show up (enabled or disabled) you are missing some boilerplate file, namely `registration.php` in `/Vendor/Module/` or `module.xml` in `/Vendor/Module/etc` folder.

If it shows up under disabled modules use `bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module` and run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

afterwards.